# @Transactional on class and getters/setters in @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, transactions, autowired, spring-transactions

when my code went through a code review, an error was pointed out.

code for example:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class ClassA {
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setJdbcTemplate(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public method1() {
      //some logic with transaction
    }
    
    ...

    public methodN() {
      //some logic with transaction
    }
}
```

I want everything method (method1...methodN) to be transactional.
But then, setter also in transactional. And the code-reviewers said it was wrong (pointed out the error).

But I don't understand why it's bad. What problems can be when using the transactional on the class (and setter also)?

Comment: You don't want to invoke transaction functionality where it's not necessary (so class level `@Transactional` is usually a no-no). It's very important to understand how the transaction boundaries work, so you need to know what you're doing and the annotation parameters behaviour, as well as how the transaction is propagated from one method to another.

Comment: @Kayaman, I agree, but in this code, what problems can there be?

Comment: Why didn't the people in the code review explain why it's bad? Sounds like your process is wrong if you only got told that something is bad and not why it's bad.

Comment: Ditch setter, use constructor injection instead. That being said, they are wrong. There is no transactional proxy at the moment the `setJdbcTemplate` is being called and thus it doesn't use a transaction. The transactional proxy is being created **after** all the properties have been set.